# Job ID for daily System Managed reports for Transaction Revenue

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Tring to find a way to download the daily system generated transaction revenue reports, but can't see any reference to them in the API documentation - any clues?

Manually logging in and downloading every day isn't ideal.

Tried using the Analytics and Reporting API method jobs.list but it doesn't seem to return an ID for any jobs where those reports could be held.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.